# Return string using RegEx if starts with one word but not another word

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to return the entire string if it starts with `page` but not `pager`.
I tried the example below but it does not work for me.

Example of a single-pass regex that contains alpha but does not contain beta (found on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063258/unix-grep-regex-containing-x-but-not-containing-y)):

```
^((?!beta).)*alpha((?!beta).)*$
```

However if you try `page` but not `pager` this does not work:

```
^((?!pager).)*page((?!pager).)*$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
^(?!pager)page.*$
```

or:

```
^page(?!r).*$
```

Both will allow `'pager'` to be in the string, but not at the start.

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
^page(?:[^r].*)?$
```

Comment: Actually, it won't work in all cases: it does not match `'page'` because with `[^r]` you ask to match any character but `'r'`.

Comment: Why not use `^page([^r].*)?$` simply now?

Comment: It's a habit. I use groups quite a lot, so never capture unless it's required. It doesn't matter here.