# Regex matching everything starting with "/api" but not finishing with ".jpg" or "statistics"

Tags: regex, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I need a regex to use with Chrome's network log to show only API calls except to two specific endpoints:

Ex.:

I want to show everything containing `/api/`:

```
http://localhost:8081/api/software-features
http://localhost:8081/api/user-groups/logged-user-group
http://localhost:8081/api/user-groups/%7B4D7E2585-32E3-4794-A0F3-4FE7D56D27AE%7D/permissions/system
http://localhost:8081/api/servers/%7B499C3279-CD5D-402E-A60B-6AE0B5A21EE0%7D/cameras
etc...
```

Except when it ends with `/image-640x480.jpg` or `/statistics`:

```
http://localhost:8081/api/servers/%7B499C3279-CD5D-402E-A60B-6AE0B5A21EE0%7D/cameras/0/streams/0/statistics
http://localhost:8081/api/servers/%7B499C3279-CD5D-402E-A60B-6AE0B5A21EE0%7D/cameras/0/streams/0/image-640x480.jpg
```

These two are constantly requested by the front-end and cause noise in the log.

Comment: You've told us what the regular expression is failing to do, but haven't shown us the regular expression.

Comment: https://regex101.com/ try and learn by yourself

Comment: I tried at http://www.regexr.com/ but everything is failing. It's a very complex case for my regex-foo. I wouldn't be asking for help if I wouldn't be needing it. I mean they say that you can "get help from experts" in this place, right?

Comment: What regex flavor?

Comment: @NicolasMaltais It's to use on Chrome's developer console, in the filter on the Network tab. I'm not sure what are the limitations there.

Comment: Since you've mentioned learning regex. Try this [regexone.com](http://regexone.com)
It has exercises and is better than most sites that teach regex.

Comment: Well, if the string starts with `/api`, you may try `^/api(?!.*(?:[.]jpg|statistics)$)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It works, thanks! Do you mind writing an answer explaining it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unix grep regex containing 'x' but not containing 'y'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063258/unix-grep-regex-containing-x-but-not-containing-y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match a string starting with `/api` and not ending with a couple of alternatives, you need to use a regex with a negative lookaround:

```
^/api(?!.*(?:[.]jpg|statistics)$)
```

**Details**:

- `^`  - start of a string
- `/api` - a literal text at the start of the string
- `(?!.*(?:[.]jpg|statistics)$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are any 0+ chars other than linebreak symbols after `/api` and there are `.jpg` (`[.]jpg`) or (`|`) `statistics` at the end of the string (`$`).

Answer (score 1):

Not a regular expression, but i believe it solves the problem:

```
(str.search(/\/api/i) >=0 && str.search(/\.jpg/i) == -1 && str.search(/\/statistics/i) == -1 )
```

Trying this on your samples:

```
const urls = [
  "http://localhost:8081/api/software-features",
  "http://localhost:8081/api/user-groups/logged-user-group",
  "http://localhost:8081/api/user-groups/%7B4D7E2585-32E3-4794-A0F3-4FE7D56D27AE%7D/permissions/system",
  "http://localhost:8081/api/servers/%7B499C3279-CD5D-402E-A60B-6AE0B5A21EE0%7D/cameras",
  "http://localhost:8081/api/servers/%7B499C3279-CD5D-402E-A60B-6AE0B5A21EE0%7D/cameras/0/streams/0/statistics",
  "http://localhost:8081/api/servers/%7B499C3279-CD5D-402E-A60B-6AE0B5A21EE0%7D/cameras/0/streams/0/image-640x480.jpg"
];

console.log([for (url of urls) (url.search(/\/api/i) >=0 && url.search(/\.jpg/i) == -1 && url.search(/\/statistics/i) == -1 )])

// Array [ true, true, true, true, false, false ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/FoOop2/1) too, it works in most regex engines

```
^.*\/api\/(?!.*(?:\.jpg|statistics)$).*$
```

- `^` matches start of the string
- `.*\/api\/` matches `\api\` and everything before
- `(?!.*(?:\.jpg|statistics)$)` this is a negative lookahead, the match will stop if next characters are anything `.*` followed by `.jpg` or `statistics` and the end of the string
- `.*$` matches everything after `/api/` in case the negative lookahead doesn't match