# Grep this but not that with -C option

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I have a similar question to this: [Unix grep regex containing 'x' but not containing 'y'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063258/unix-grep-regex-containing-x-but-not-containing-y)

The twist is that, I d like to grep the files around my search with -C5.

So the `grep this myfile | grep -v that` won't work.

example: let say `myfile` is as follows:

```
**
**
alpha
**
**
##
##
alpha beta
##
##
```

I d like to grep :

```
**
**
alpha
**
**
```

how would I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `gnu grep` with a PCRE regex:

```
grep -C2 -P '^(?!.*beta).*alpha' file
```

```
**
**
alpha
**
**
```

Regex `'^(?!.*beta).*alpha'` uses a negative lookahead to match a line that contains `alpha` anywhere but doesn't contain `beta`.

If `gnu grep` is not available:

```
awk '/alpha/ && !/beta/{print line[NR-2]; print line[NR-1]; n=NR}
     n && NR<=n+2; {line[NR]=$0}' file
```

```
**
**
alpha
**
**
```

Comment: Your regex solution and its explanation is not correct. It must be `grep -C2 -P '^(?!.*beta).*alpha' file`, because `(?!.*beta)alpha` matches any line with `alpha` word that is not followed with `beta` anwhere *after* `alpha`, and `beta alpha` would get returned.

Comment: Yes good point Wiktor. It should have been `'^(?!.*beta).*alpha'` to match `alpha` anywhere.