# Select lines that contain a digit but not a pair of that digit in Bash using regular expressions

Tags: regex, grep

I have a file containing one number per line.

*data.txt*

```
00700
00100
07070
01010
07700
07770
70000
10000
00007
```

I want to print lines that contain a digit `7` and at the same time do not contain its pair `77`. I wrote a simple script for this.

*script.sh*

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cat data.txt | grep -E '\d*7' | grep -v -E '\d*77'
```

Quick explanation of the regular expression above:

- First take any digit zero or more times.
- Then take 7.
- If the line satisfies the rules above run the search again.
- Take any digit zero or more times.
- Take double 7.
- If the line again satisfies the rules, remove it from the selection (the `-v` option inverts the selection).

This works fine and outputs the desired result.

*output*

```
00700
07070
70000
00007
```

However I had to start the `grep` program twice. I then tried a different regular expression.

*script.sh*

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cat data.txt | grep -E '\d*7[0-689]?\d*'
```

Which should in my understanding:

- Take any number zero or more times.
- Then `7`.
- Then any number except 7 zero or once.
- Then any number until the end of the line.

However it also selects the lines that contain `77`.

*output*

```
00700
07070
07700
07770
70000
00007
```

Is there a better way that starts `grep` or any other program that uses regular expressions only once?

Comment: Incorrect dupe. OP is asking `I want to print lines that contain a digit 7 and at the same time do not contain its pair 77`

Comment: `cat data.txt | grep -v 77 | grep 7` probably the easiest here

Comment: @AvenDesta: Please read full question. OP already knows how to run `grep` twice and wants to avoid doing that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unix grep regex containing 'x' but not containing 'y'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063258/unix-grep-regex-containing-x-but-not-containing-y)

Comment: Please read question completely. Obviously OP already knows how to use a `grep` for `containing 'x' but not containing 'y'`. This question is about doing it in single `grep` and both GNU and POSIX solutions are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this `awk` alternative:

```sh
awk '/7/ && !/77/' data.txt

00700
07070
70000
00007
```

An equivalent `gnu grep` would be this:

```sh
grep -P '^(?!.*77).*7' data.txt
```

Or in POSIX `grep`:

```sh
grep -vE '77|^[^7]+$' data.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

With shown samples only, this could be done by simple regex in GNU `grep` command.

```
grep -P '(?<!7)7(?!7)' Input_file
```

OR with covering edge case of 7's coming in starting should be dealt with try:

```
grep -P '^(?!.*77)(?=.*7)' Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

- Using `-P` option to enable PCRE regex here.
- First using `(?<!7)` negative look behind to make sure 7 is not preceded by `7`.
- Then using negative lookahead `(?!7)` to make sure `7` is not followed further by any 7 as per need.

Answer (score 1):

This would do it using PCRE:

```
grep -P '^(?=.*7)((?!77).)*$' Input_file
```

https://regex101.com/r/ECrwky/1

Comment: However that also prints `00100`, `01010` and `10000`.

Comment: @sanitizedUser Well that's embarrassing, fixed!